# NestJS Mongo TypeError: this.memberModel is not a constructor

Tags: mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I can't seem to figure this test out in my NestJS app. Following the documentation for connecting [NestJS & MongoDB](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection) I receive the error from the screenshot below when trying to run the `createMember` spec. I have added the service and its respective spec below as well. The public repo is https://github.com/alobban/zeta-nestjs/tree/mongo/src/member.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { Member } from './member.interface';
import { CreateMemberDto } from './dto/create-member-dto';

@Injectable()
export class MembersService {
  members = [
    { firstName: 'Jake', lastName: 'Miller', lineName: 'State Farm' },
  ];

  constructor(@InjectModel('Member') private readonly memberModel: Model<Member>) {}

  async getMembers(): Promise<Member[]> {
    return await this.memberModel.find().exec();
  }

  async createMember(createMemberDto: CreateMemberDto): Promise<Member> {
    const createdMember = new this.memberModel(createMemberDto);
    return await createdMember.save();
  }
}
```

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MongooseModule, getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { MembersService } from './members.service';

const members = [
  { firstName: 'Jake', lastName: 'Miller', lineName: 'State Farm' },
];

describe('MembersService', () => {
  let membersService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MembersService,
        {
          provide: getModelToken('Member'),
          useValue: {
            find: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(members),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    membersService = await module.get<MembersService>(MembersService);
  });

  describe('getMembers', () => {
    it('calls getMembers and returns an array of Members', () => {
      expect(membersService.getMembers()).resolves.toEqual(members);
    });
  });

  describe('createMember', () => {
    it('calls membersService.createMember and returns result', async () => {
      const save = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true);

      expect(save).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      const result = await membersService.createMember('newMember');

      expect(save).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007200/unit-testing-nestjs-mongoose-services/58555364#58555364)

Comment: @PooyaHaratian It worked, but I don't understand why. Is there material that explains this workaround? I am new to Jest and NestJS

Comment: Actually it's nothing special, in the official NestJs documentation they use an object, to mock mongoose, and it will be used in your service as `this.memberModel`. So in your createUser method you call an that object as a class, and that's the reason of the error.

Comment: I hadn't seen all the documentation, so I had no idea. Do you know where in the docs this is stated?

Comment: I think the docs didn't mention this directly. I figured it myself.

Comment: Do you mind pasting your answer or make reference the link to your answer below so I can mark it as my official answer and give you credit?

Comment: what if you change your save call to this.memberModel.create(createMemberDto), this way there is no need to pass the object as class?